# Should I htmlspecialchars() variables inside <title></title>?

Tags: php, security, xss

Is it necessary to filter/escape unsafe variables in `<title>` or other tags in `<head>` to prevent XSS?

Comment: Just because you don't know how to hack something, doesn't mean you shouldn't sanitize it anyways.  As somebody below pointed out, there is a way to XSS your webpage, always assume there is a way and never cut corners on your sanity checking.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Strictly speaking it is necessary to do `htmlspecialchars()` on *absolutely everything* you output to a web page from PHP.

If you come to a point where this produces a wrong result (i.e. HTML code is showing up in the browser because of double encoding) you have found a design flaw in your application.

XSS would not be a problem if people would stick to this simple rule.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You should *always* use the `htmlspecialchars` function on values that may contain HTML special characters.