# XSS attack in title-tag

Tags: php, html, security, xss

I have a form where users can fill in a news article. This contains a title and body.
For each page to have a unique title, I'm using the user input (title) in the `<title>`-tags:

```
<title>$userinput</title>
```

I'm wondering - is it possible for the user to perform an XSS-attack this way? Should I escape this user input using `htmlspecialchars`?

The same also applies to `<meta>`-tags. I'm using user input for the description:

```
<meta name="description" content="$userinput" />
```

Can a user perform XSS-attacks in `<title>` and `<meta>`-tags?

Comment: As soon as you write unescaped HTML to a webpage, there is a possibility of XSS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I htmlspecialchar() variables inside <title></title>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/638057/should-i-htmlspecialchar-variables-inside-title-title)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Should I escape this user input using htmlspecialchars?

Yes. Location doesn't matter. All user input should be escaped.

References:

- [What are the best practices for avoiding xss attacks in a PHP site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71328/what-are-the-best-practices-for-avoiding-xss-attacks-in-a-php-site)
- [What's the best method for sanitizing user input with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php+xss

Answer (score 3):

He could close any tag first:

`</title><script> alert('here I am') </script>`

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to perform an XSS attack that way.

I'd use [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) to begin with.
Also you might want to consider [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/).
Lastly, you might want to consider [PHPIDS](https://phpids.org/). That would be a bit overkill for most situations though...